# MySQL Update foreign key with values

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
ANIMALS
---------
id
name
specie_name
id_specie

SCPECIE
---------
id
specie_name
```

In Animals table I have all values except id_specie. How can I update rows in animals to get ids from table Specie by comparing specie_name from both tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the two tables. Try this:

```
UPDATE Animals a INNER JOIN SPECIE b
        on a.specie_name =  b.specie_name
SET    a.id_specie = b.id
```

**[FOR REFERENCE](http://blog.ookamikun.com/2008/03/mysql-update-with-join.html)**

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE ANIMALS SET id_specie = (SELECT id FROM SPECIE WHERE specie_name = ANIMALS.specie_name)`